# MySQL join query with only one record from joined table, ordered by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL I want to join in one query.

**Table one opc_tag:**

```
id name
```

**Table two opc_data:**

```
id tag_id value created_at
```

I want to list all rows from opc_tag with the last record from opc_data based on the "**created_at**" field.

I've tried to find it on Google, but it does not work.
The following query selected the tags with multiple records from **opc_data-table**.

```
SELECT t.*, d.*
FROM opc_tag t LEFT JOIN opc_data d ON t.id = d.tag_id
WHERE d.created_at = (
    SELECT MAX(d.created_at)
    FROM opc_data d2
    WHERE d2.tag_id = t.id
)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. As your issue is probably not as simple as we might think at first, you should perhaps edit your question to show an *example* of actual input data and the *expected* output. Once done, while waiting for answers you should take a look on our help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will do it:

```
SELECT t.*,d.* FROM opc_tag t 
LEFT JOIN opc_data d ON t.id = d.tag_id
WHERE d.created_at = (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM opc_data WHERE tag_id = t.id
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

if you want to show all tags, even those that have no data, use this in the where clause:

```
WHERE d.created_at = (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM opc_data WHERE tag_id = t.id
) OR d.created_at IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will get the last tag_id entered in the  `opc_data`  by `ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1` and returns the data against tag_id from the `opc_tag`

```
SELECT *
FROM opc_tag 
WHERE id= (
    SELECT tag_id
    FROM opc_data 
   ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 
)
```

Comment: add in subquery `t.id = d.tag_id`

Comment: When I run that query, I only got one record (the last one) from opc_tag, but no opc_data fields. I need the value field and created_at field from that table.

Comment: this is what you asked for **I want to list all rows from opc_tag with the last record from opc_data based on the "created_at" field**